# How can this jquery selector be shortened?

Tags: jquery

I've got the following selector:

```
$(this).children('li').children('a')
```

It seems a bit clunky, can it be shortened?

Comment: I suck at this, but `$(this).children('li a')` does not work? EDIT: By the way, this is a pretty short and nice selector in my opinion.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: That would select all `a` children of `this` which are also descendants of `li` elements. So no, it is not the same and won't work, as `this` is probably a `ul` element and does not have `a` children. Passing such selectors to `children` is a common misconception.

Comment: Yeah, it does the job but I was wondering if it is possible to replace the 'children' methods with something more elegant?

Comment: By using classes `$( ".class-for-a-element", this );`. This way only one jQuery object is constructed. You could also use `$( "li a", this );` but the performance benefit is lost.

Comment: @OptimusCrime To answer your question, it does not work. (unless you mean `.find` instead of `.children`)

Comment: Thanks. I usually go with find in these cases, so I was not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('li > a',this);......................
```

Comment: That's not the same thing because it allows the `<li>` element to be a descendant of `this` instead of restricting it to immediate children.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), but I don't think it's much shorter really:

`$(this).find("> li > a");`

Note the use of the `>` child selector, so it only finds `li` elements that are direct children of `this` (as the `children` method in your original code would).

Comment: From the docs: *The `$("> elem", context)` selector will be deprecated in a future release.*... not sure if this applies to `find` as well.

Comment: @FelixKling - It probably does count for `find` as well, considering selector context is implemented using `find` anyway, so it's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shortened very little, so it looks like this:

```
$('li', this).children('a')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).children("li > a")
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one, in my opinion is `$(">li>a",this)`.

If you are sure there is no other `li`'s in A innerHTML, maybe you can short to `$("li>a",this)`.